# Mysql Join same table multiple entries

Tags: mysql

I have the table 'meta' with the following fields and values:

```
 •col1  •col2 •col3   •REL •JOIN
   1     John  Smith       1    0   
   2     Peter Pan         2    0  
   3     Brat  Pitt        3    0  
   4     Sarah Palin       1    00 
   5     King  David       2    00
   6     Coco  Sha         3    00
   7     Santa Claus       3    00
```

I'd like to loop through and display a list combine the data from the same table as below :

```
•col1  •col2 •col3 •REL •JOIN  •col1  •col2 •col3  •REL •JOIN

   1    John  Smith  1    0      1    John  Smith   1    0

   1    John  Smith  1    0      2    Peter Pan     2    0

   1    John  Smith  1    0      3    Brat  Pitt    3    0

   4    Sarah Palin  1    00     4    Sarah Palin   1    00

   4    Sarah Palin  1    00     5    King  David   2    00

   4    Sarah Palin  1    00     6    Coco  Sha     3    00

   4    Sarah Palin  1    00     7    Santa Claus   3    00
```

if *REL = '1'  then use col1, col2 and col3 with *REL = '1' in the next join
   *JOIN   is the key for the final join

Comment: And you've tried what so far to solve your problem?

Comment: Can you explain the join condition logic little more?

Comment: if *REL = '1' then use col1, col2 and col3 with *REL = '1' in the next join
 *JOIN is the key for the final join

Comment: I have updated the answer. Checkout now.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement above join logic as below.

```
    select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.REL, a.joinKey,
           b.col1, b.col2, b.col3, b.REL, b.joinKey
      from meta a join meta b on a.joinKey = b.joinKey
      where a.REL = 1;
```

A sql fiddle is setup for this. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf126/2)

Comment: Thanks Mark. I updated the answer per update in question

Comment: I'm glad that solution worked for you. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to join on the first character of col1

```
select a.*, b.*
from meta a
join meta b on a.col1 = left(b.col1,1)
```